# sequentially run functions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, filesystems, lpr

I'm very new to node and have run into issues with running some functions sequentially and the use of callbacks. I have tried to use the async module, but, I think I'm missing something because it does my functions out of order.

In the most simplest terms I would like to retrieve some data in the form of url params and then:
1. write them to a file
2. lpr print them
3. delete the file

My current code deletes the file before printing.ie step 3 before step 2.Would anyone offer some advice on how best to perform these in order? Thanks in advance.

```
router.get('/zplprint/:barcode/:zpl', function(req, res) {
var zpl = req.params.zpl;
var filename  = appDir + "/uploads/" + req.params.barcode + ".zpl";
console.log(req.params.zpl);
res.send("received zpl: " + req.params.zpl);

async.series([
    function(callback){
        fs.writeFile(filename, zpl, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("The file was saved! to "+filename);
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        CupsPrinterName = nconf.get('Print:PrinterName');
        console.log(CupsPrinterName);
        var cmd = 'lpr -P ' + CupsPrinterName + ' -o raw ' + filename;
        exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            // command output is in stdout'
            console.log(cmd);
            console.log("file printed");
        });
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        fs.unlink(filename, function (err) {
            console.log('   deleting ' + filename);

        });
        callback();
    }
]);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `callback()` function at the same level of `exec()`, exec is asynchronous and will log "file printed" after deleting the file because callback() was called outside of `exec()` and not when the function ends. Try calling callback after printing:

```
function(callback){
    CupsPrinterName = nconf.get('Print:PrinterName');
    console.log(CupsPrinterName);
    var cmd = 'lpr -P ' + CupsPrinterName + ' -o raw ' + filename;
    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        // command output is in stdout'
        console.log(cmd);
        console.log("file printed");
        callback();
    });        
},
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something. This seems to have done the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var Q = require('q')


router.get('/zplprint/:barcode/:zpl', function(req, res) {
var zpl = req.params.zpl;
var filename  = appDir + "/uploads/" + req.params.barcode + ".zpl";
console.log(req.params.zpl);
res.send("received zpl: " + req.params.zpl);


    function first(callback){
        var d1 = Q.defer();
        fs.writeFile(filename, zpl, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                d1.reject(err);

            }
            console.log("The file was saved! to "+filename);
            d1.resolve("success");
        });
        return d1.promise
    }



    function second(callback){
        var d2  = Q.defer()
        CupsPrinterName = nconf.get('Print:PrinterName');
        console.log(CupsPrinterName);
        var cmd = 'lpr -P ' + CupsPrinterName + ' -o raw ' + filename;
        exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
           if(error){
               d2.reject()
           }
            console.log(cmd);
            console.log("file printed");
            d2.resolve()
        });
        return d2.promise
    }



    function third(callback){
        var d3 = Q.defer()
        fs.unlink(filename, function (err) {
            if(err){
                d3.reject()
            }
            console.log('   deleting ' + filename);
                d3.resolve()
        });
        return d3.promise
    }

  first().then(second).then(third).fail(function(){
    console.log("Error !!!!")


})

});
```

Prerequisites:

```
npm install q
```

the best ever promise structure